# Google Chrome seems to ignore cellpadding + cellspacing

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, button, html-table

I have a table with a tr and two tds. First td contains an input(text), the second another input (image). The second input is supposed to be a button. I've set cellpadding and cellspacing to zero so that the text input and the image button can be attached with no spaces in between. This works fine in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome. Chrome keeps leaving a few pixels of space between the text input and the button. I tried using CSS but nothing seems to work. Any idea what Chrome's problem might be?

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
.search{ 
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    color: #4D4D4D; 
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; 
    height: 21px; 
    outline: none; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
        <form method="post"> 
            <tr><td><input type="text" size="30" class="search"></td> 
            <td><input type="image" src="button.gif" name="submit" id="submit" width="77px" height="21px"></td></tr> 
        </form> 
    </table> 
</body>
```

Comment: "tried using css" Did you reset the paddings/margins properly? (on both, the table cells and the input)

Comment: Got some code you can show us?

Comment: @weber, edit your original question to add the code you're using that's not displaying correctly. Comments are definitely not the place for code.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to move the `<form>` tag outside of the `<table>` you're going to cause yourself trouble that way.

Next, you need to set the padding on your `td`s to 0:

```
form td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

That should get rid of any extra spacing you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

A stackoverflow user [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180652/1670956):

> Just mentioning that `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` have been made obsolete, and I received a shock when Google Chrome 23 didn't support it.

Anyway I can't find any reference on the internet!

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, try `border-collapse: collapse` on the table via css.

Also, you might want to look into other means as using a `table` for layout is not the way forward these days and it sounds like that's what you're doing.

Comment: Would you elaborate on `not the way forward these days`, please?

Comment: @BobSort I'd say that using CSS for layout is the way forward. Using a `<table>` to layout elements on a page is something people used to do in the dark ages of front-end development.

Comment: As I understand it is your personal opinion. I am not saying it is right o wrong. I am yet to find a strong reference to why tables should not be used for arranging content. As far as I know, css3 has some styles to arrange contents in `column`s.

Comment: It's my personal opinion but I'd like to think that it's more or less based on something :) In this case on using the right tools for the right job. Sure you can hammer in a nail with a big enough screwdriver, but that doesn't make a screwdriver a hammer.

Comment: @Matijs Your vague hints and metaphors aren't particularly useful to users like myself who are still finding your answer in 2016. Perhaps you'd be so kind as to update your answer with relevant sources to support your opinion which is `based on something`? What is it based on?

Comment: @Dan the web and what we use to build it evolves. CSS nowadays has much more powerful ways to layout pages than ever before. Tables are a semantic element and should be used for tabular data, not for laying out whatever they contain on a page.

Comment: @Matijs `has much more powerful ways`. You're still evading the question. Name one. That's all anyone was ever asking.

Comment: @Dan floats, `display: inline-block` (now frowned upon by some as well and both a bit hacky), `position: absolute/relative` and nowadays more modern ways for layout such as CSS Flexible Box Layout Module 1 and in the near future CSS Grid Layout Module 1.

Comment: @Matijs Thank you! Now I have lots of keywords to go research. Much appreciated.